# mega menu going out of window

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/vxaAE/

I tried to integrate this menu in my project but it comes to me with two problems.

**-** sub menu going out of window when I have this scenario-
http://jsfiddle.net/vxaAE/

**-** I tried to give submenu's width to auto, because it would be according to sub menu's length.

How do I get this working?

**CSS-**

```
  .mega-wrapper {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .mega-nav {
            position: relative;
            width: auto;
            height: 59px;
            background: #252428;
        }


            .mega-nav ul .mega-ul {
                display: block;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                list-style: 0;
            }

            .mega-nav .mega-ul li {
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block;
            }

                .mega-nav .mega-ul li a {
                    display: block;
                    font-size: 1em;
                    color: #fff;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    padding: 0 15px;
                }

                    .mega-nav .mega-ul li a:hover, .mega-nav .mega-ul li:hover > a {
                        background: #333;
                    }

                .mega-nav .mega-ul li:hover > .mega-div {
                    display: block;
                }

       .mega-div {
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 0;
            width: 450px;
            height: auto;
            padding: 20px 30px;
            background: #333;
            display: none;
            z-index:1000;
        }

        .mega-ul li ul {
            float: left;
            width: 23%;
            margin: 0 2% 15px 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
        }

            .mega-ul li ul li {
                display: block;
            }

                .mega-ul li ul li a {
                    float: left;
                    display: block;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: auto;
                    line-height: 1.3em;
                    color: #888;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    padding: 1px 0;
                }

                .mega-ul li ul li:first-child a {
                    font-size: 1.2em;
                    color: #8dc63f;
                }

                .mega-ul li ul li a:hover {
                    color: #fff;
                    background: none;
                }

        .mega-ul ul li:first-child a:hover {
            color: #fff;
        }

        /* clearfix */
        .mega-nav .mega-ul:after {
            content: ".";
            display: block;
            clear: both;
            visibility: hidden;
            line-height: 0;
            height: 0;
        }

        .mega-nav .mega-ul {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .header-title {
            line-height: 59px;
        }
```

Any help would be greate appreciated.

Comment: What if the elements in the submenu are dynamical and you don't know the size of .mega-fiv? 
This might give you some work to do, but look into this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vxaAE/3/)**

You can do this:

```
.mega-nav .mega-ul li:nth-child(1n+6):hover .mega-div{
    right:0;
    left:auto;
}
```

This way, starting from the 6th `.mega-nav .mega-ul li:nth-child(1n+6):hover .mega-div`, it will align to `right:0;` going the other way.

This is thanks to `nth-child(1n+6)`, which means starting from the 6th element, every one after has this property.

It's not the *prettiest* alternative, but you can mess around, making it `left:-50%`, or `right:50%`.

If you know how many you have and will always be that way and you know what one works where, you can just use `:nth-child(n)` and style that way. (n being the number in which that element appears).

Answer (score 0):

Remove position relative from `li` tag

```
.mega-ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative; // remove it 
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vxaAE/1/

Comment: This is useless, if you're on the last tab you won't be able to pick an item from the sub menu